# Downgrade SQL of a managed instance

Tags: azure-sql-database

In an attempt to stay up to date , we opted for a managed instance in azure to support our SQL database. Our application only goes up to version SQL 2019 but the managed instance is SQL 2022. Is there any configuration to update the SQL down to 2019 and keep stable at this version?

Comment: I'm confused: you are attempting to stay up to date while using a version that's five years old?

Comment: Does [this](https://asmed.com/microsoft-azure-how-to-create-a-windows-2019-server-image/) help?

Answer (score 0):

With any of the flavors of Azure SQL Database(Managed Instance, DTU-model, vCore, Hyperscale) you cannot disable automatic updates, Azure SQL will always run the latest version and latest cumulative update.

However, you can try to change the [compatibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/managed-instance/transact-sql-tsql-differences-sql-server?view=azuresql#compatibility-levels) to 150 on user database, to see if the application can work as expected that way.